# nvram command not found

Tags: terminal, startup, nvram

When attempting to check the change the contents of the nvram (adding bootup chime, etc.), I am continually returned with the error: `nvram: command not found`. This occurs even when I attempt to just check the contents of the nvram, simply returning `-bash: nvram: command not found`. I can't seem to find anything addressing such a problem on 10.13.6. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

The full path to it is:

```
/usr/sbin/nvram
```

Can you run that instead? Might be something wrong with your BASH environment that's preventing it from seeing the binary.